# Is there a function to skip steps in a for loop?

Tags: vb.net

I want to skip steps in a nested for loops of like 9 loops but the code will express my question and predicament:

```
Sub question()
    For x = 0 To 10
        For y = 0 To 10
            If x = 5 And y = 7 Then
                'skip to x = 8
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set x = 8

```
Sub Question()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    For x = 0 To 10
        For y = 0 To 10
            If x = 5 And y = 7 Then
                x = 8
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thought I tried that on a different program a while back but just tried it and it worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: If you want the next step to be x = 8, I think you need to set x = 7 based on the docs (which state that *counter* is incremented each time `Next` is encountered).  Depending on the contents of the loop, you may want `Continue For` immediately after setting `x`.

Comment: yes you are right, but all depends on how he uses x. Suppose he wants print all values of x. If he does a Console.WriteLine after nested for, x must be set to 8, if he does the Console.WriteLine before the nested loop x must be set to 7. Question is a bit generic about that, but I think I aswered correctly about how to skip steps.